# How to write I2C protocol timing constraints?

Tags: fpga, i2c, timing, timing-analysis

How do you normally write clock timing cons for I2C? Assuming 1 SDA line, 1 SCL line, 1 APB reference CLK called PCLK.

Q. What are the relation of PCLK to SCL in this protocol? Does it matter if it is in slave/master mode?

Q. Do we need separate SDC for slave and master?

Mode of operation is slow - SCL is 1 MHz (slow with respect to system APB clock which is 150 MHz).

I have currently defined clocks at the input port for SCL coming from the external bump in my design. I do not know how to write these into slave and master modes.

Comment: There are many issues in this question. First of all, 1 MHz I2C is not slow, it is generally out of limits what chips normally support. You also need to define what you mean by apb and pclk. They might not have anything to do with it.

Comment: I think you mixed up quite a few things here. I2C has a clock (SCL) line and a data (SDA) line. Master generates clock, data is bidirectional. All slave share the same clock and data lines.

Comment: [I2C]{https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf} is a communications protocol invented by Nexperia (Philips) separate from the microcontroller. There is not enough information in the question to answer any of your questions.

Comment: @Julien Clock can be bidirectional too, not just data. Slaves can use it to slow down communication.